# listView advice

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want create listview without layout_height. I mean if there is 100 item in listview, no need to create scrolling. it just have to take place so many height as it need. Is there a way to do this?
Anytime I add items the listView height should increase but no need scrolling.

Comment: 100 items and without scrolling? Are you sure?

Comment: It will not scroll if there is not enough data to scroll.

Comment: yes, no need to scroll any other way.

Comment: could you upload an image, what do you want is still not clear. if you don't want scrolling, how would you display 100 items to the user.

Comment: Do you mean that you want user to scroll the list up and down but there should be no progressbar visible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this programatically:
After knowing how many entries you got you have to manuallay set the layout_height in Java code to `(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() / number_of_entries)`.
But I still don't get why you want to do that. If you got 100 entries on a Nexus S you got 8 Pixel for each entry. Way to less to read or klick them precicely.

Comment: I want use ScrollView, that's why.

Comment: Than you are totally wrong. A scrollView needs to know exactly how big its content is, otherwise it will collapse. And scrollView inside listView and the other way round isn't working at all.

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you want to do (display what data, why scrollview and not listview, ...)

Comment: My UI is about some kind of information. there are many imageViews, textviews, listView, buttons, and they can't display without scrollview

Comment: You can only use a listview for everything and modify the getView-Method like you want it (return different views for every entry) or you replace the listView in your scroll View with a button that opens an AlertDialog that contains the content of your listview. These are the only two options i can tell you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6060/discussion-between-fish40-and-thommy)